# How do I constrain my Python history to a virtual env?

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv

Python 3 appears (at least by default) to keep the history of interactive commands in a global location, `~/.python_history`. As a result, commands issued in different virtual envs are merged.

Is there a way to segregate my Python history so that each virtual env has (and access) its own?

Answer (score 0):

To implement this you need to have a [`PYTHONSTARTUP`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/readline.html?highlight=pythonstartup#example) file. The following works for me:

```
def init():
    import os

    # readline/pyreadline

    try:
        import readline
        histfiles = ['~/.python_history']
        if 'VIRTUAL_ENV' in os.environ:
            histfiles.append('$VIRTUAL_ENV/.python_history')
        for histfile in histfiles:
            try:
                histfile = os.path.expandvars(histfile)
                histfile = os.path.expanduser(histfile)
                readline.read_history_file(histfile)
            except IOError:
                pass  # No such file

        def savehist():
            histsize = os.environ.get('HISTSIZE')
            if histsize:
                try:
                    histsize = int(histsize)
                except ValueError:
                    pass
                else:
                    readline.set_history_length(histsize)
            histfile = histfiles[-1]
            histfile = os.path.expandvars(histfile)
            histfile = os.path.expanduser(histfile)
            readline.write_history_file(histfile)

        import atexit
        atexit.register(savehist)

    except (ImportError, AttributeError):
        # no readline or atexit, or readline doesn't have
        # {read,write}_history_file - ignore the error
        pass

init()
del init
```

Adapt to your needs. See my complete [`init.py`](https://phdru.name/Software/dotfiles/python/init.py.html) ([text version](https://phdru.name/Software/dotfiles/python/init.py.txt); git repository at https://git.phdru.name/dotfiles.git/, see the file `lib/python/init.py`).

Comment: Does it help? A little bit?